# Error in external php class include in Laravel 5.3?

Tags: php, csv, laravel-5.3

I have a php library class file called, `CsvClass.php`. I place this file in the location, `app/Libraries/CsvClass.php`. I have seen [Some](http://laraveldaily.com/how-to-use-external-classes-and-php-files-in-laravel-controller/) url where this kind of problem have the solution. So as per the direction I added `namespace App\Libraries;` and `use App\Libraries\CsvClass;` in the controller. But for this I have this error at the time of load the controller. `FatalErrorException in ImportController.php line 17:Class 'App\Libraries\Controller' not found`.

So I comment `app/Libraries/CsvClass.php` and run so the controller is loading. At the top portion of the controller is now look like this,

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
//namespace App\Libraries;

use App\Libraries\CsvClass;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse;
use Clusterpoint\Client;
use DateTime;
use Session;
use Excel;
```

But when I try to use the class and there is an error of,

```
FatalErrorException in ImportController.php line 120: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\parseCSV' not found
```

I try trying to use this class,

```
$csv = new parseCSV();
$csv->auto($path);
$full_data=$csv->data;
```

Here `$path` contain the path of the csv file. This function is working in a separate php file. But not in Laravel. I am using version 5.3. And follow the rules of how to import the external files in laravel. But not understand why the error is coming. Please help me.

I am  using a CSV library to read csv file. The Library is [here](https://github.com/parsecsv/parsecsv-for-php).

Comment: Can you show your file `CsvClass.php`?

Comment: You can download the file from https://github.com/parsecsv/parsecsv-for-php link.  already give the link in the question.

Comment: make sure you have the namespace set for CsvClass.php to mach App\Libraries\CsvClass in your use statement.

Comment: This is the same library file. I only change the name to CsvClass.php. Original file name is parsecsv.lib.php.

Comment: @andrew: I am actually not understanding this thing. Please help me here.

Comment: Make sure your file name and class name are same. Change the class name to `CsvClass` and try again.

Comment: I change the file name to parseCSV. And the error change to FatalErrorException in ImportController.php line 120:
Class 'App\Libraries\parseCSV' not found

Answer (score 0):

The best way to use classes without namespaces and different file name is by using composer autoloading.

1) Register your class in classmap.

```
"autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database",
            "app/Libraries/CsvClass.php"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
```

2) Run `composer dump-autoload`

Now you can access your class anywhere without providing the full path.

```
$csv = new parseCSV();
$csv->auto($path);
$full_data=$csv->data;
```

Comment: You sure that composer dump-autoload ran without any warnings or error messages? Because I tried that myself before posting and it worked for me.

Comment: Are you testing it using php artisan serve? If yes, close it and re-run. It's weird when it comes to class loading.